# What is maven variable to get full repository URL where artefact/jar is uploaded

Tags: maven, teamcity, maven-deploy-plugin

We have git -> team city -> artifactoy for CICD pipeline where build job in team city uses maven plugins to build the jars and then deploy jars to artifactory server.

I am already doing some custom processing in my CICD pipeline using team city provided variable to get the information about current build getting executed like

`maven.project.version` to get jar version getting build OR
`maven.project.name` to get the name of project.

As part of deploy job we use maven's deploy goal to deploy the jars to artifactory. As per team city logs the deployed location i.e. repository where jar will be uploaded  looks like

```
step no [2/5] uploading ... http://artifactory.mycompany.com/snapshot-local/myproject/f1/f2/f2/f4/1.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I need a variable from team city or maven variable through which I can get hold of this complete repository path where jar is getting uploaded so that I can do some customisation/processing in my CICD pipeline.

I tried to search on maven::deploy plugin portal i.e. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/ and in team city maven portal i.e. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/maven.html but could not see any meaningful link where I can see the possible maven variable for this.

Any idea anyone?